# Why is my for loop not working?

Tags: php, for-loop

Why is my for loop not working? `$_POST["report"]` is the value of the textbox.

```
<?php 
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
 $report_output="Comment:\n";
 $report_output.=$_POST["report"];
    for($i=90;$i<=strlen($report_output);$i+=90){
            $report_output=substr_replace($report_output,"\n",int($i),0);
    };
    $report_output.="\n";
$file=fopen("report.txt","a");
fwrite($file,$report_output);
fclose($file);
}?>
```

Comment: I think we'll need more info. What is $_POST['report']'s value? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: From the code you posted, I assume `$report_output` is shorter than 90 characters.

Comment: Hi, and welcome. From the information you put in the question, no one will be able to answer this question beyond an educated guess (And Grice's guess is a decent one). Specifically, we need to know the *input data* (`$_POST['report`), as well as the expected results; [a *complete* example is preferred](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also see: [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The better you make your question, the better & more useful answer you're likely to get!

Comment: We need more information. What is being sent through to $_POST['report'] is this a user entered value posted from a form, an AJAX request and is it always a number/have a default value? What is the expected result and what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume what you're trying to do is put a line break after every 90 chars. In the code you've given us, `int()` is an undefined function, that's why the loop won't work. If you're trying to cast `$i` as an integer, you do it like this `(int)$i`. But you shouldn't need to do that in this code, so the following will be fine:

```
for($i=90;$i<=strlen($report_output);$i+=90){
        $report_output=substr_replace($report_output,"\n",$i,0);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do what you wish another way as follows:

```
<?php

if( $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" ){
    $report_output = "Comment:\n";
    $report_output .= htmlspecialchars( $_POST["report"] );

    $split = str_split( $report_output, 90 );
    foreach ( $split as $portion ){
        $str .= trim( $portion ) . "\n";
    }

   $report_output = $str . "\n"; 

   $file = fopen( "report.txt","a" );
   fwrite( $file,$report_output );
   fclose( $file );
}
```

Note that it is inadvisable to immediately use a POST (or GET) variable without *first* making sure that this form data is untainted.  In this case, I used htmlspecialchars() but you might wish to take other precautions to be sure that your data is really what you expect in order to avoid potential security issues.